# I Want To Check If User Exist Before Login If Not They Must Sign Up, In Firebase Google Auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I have Login and Sign Up functionality using Firebase Google Auth and It works Fine but I want to Check If the user already Signed Up, They can't sign Up 2 times they'll have to Login. is there a Code Like:

```
if(user.exist){
  alert("Account Already exists please Login")
}else{
  auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
}
```

And vice versa if they do not exist they'll have to Sign Up:

Is This possible with google auth?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_a_users_profile add a if statement, to check if it's `null`

Comment: @EdGzi Thank you for you response, I Tried it but that prevents the pop-up to open hence the user cant sign up even if they never sign up before.

Comment: You don't need to control the user exist because if exists firebase can't create users again.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to know at least part of the user's credentials to check if they already exist in Firebase Authentication.

For example, if the user signed in with a provider that requires their email before, you'll should ask them for their email address next time and then [call `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#fetchsigninmethodsforemail) to determine if Firebase already has a user for that email address.

Comment: thank you for your response, This can only be achieved when using Email Auth not Google Auth?

Comment: how do I do it?. I changed to the Email Auth and it working fine but I am unable to make it check if user exist been trying since yesterday.

Comment: If you're having a hard time making the solution in my answer work, edit your question to [show the code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).